# Magento update products to display at frontend with images

Tags: image, magento, dynamic

I have added products in magento by executing a script (automatically). All products are configurable.

All products are assigned properly to category, category and shown properly at admin area, But some products are shown at client side, and also shown images too.

To solve this I must "edit" product than "assign image" and "save". So it works and show the product with images at client side.

Now, do anyone have idea how to "Save" product automatically or any method available in Magento to save this products programmatic

I am new to magento.

Comment: what do you mean by "shown at client side"? what exactly do you want?

Comment: culturally display in admin side all data with images but not display fronted same data and not display images for all images

Comment: i have run this code http://ka.lpe.sh/2013/02/26/magento-cant-see-product-images-in-category-page/ but display this error


There has been an error processing your request

Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.

Error log record number: 617307420

Comment: pls check the error at var/report/617307420 and paste the error here.

Comment: ";i:1;s:1486:"#0 D:\xampp\htdocs\demo\tact\app\lib\Varien\Db\Statement\Pdo\Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 D:\xampp\htdocs\demo\tact\app\lib\Zend\Db\Statement.php(300): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 D:\xampp\htdocs\demo\tact\app\lib\Zend\Db\Adapter\Abstract.php(479): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)

Comment: Please give me solution for image display in frontend

Comment: No, I want error and not it's backtrace. If you are unable to paste whole report here, pls paste it over pastebin.com and give me link.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/xpgLPrtx  i have added error code please check if possible please give me full code

Comment: http://pastebin.com/pFQe23uX   i have use this and display error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood your problem correctly, you are looking for this:

http://ka.lpe.sh/2013/02/26/magento-cant-see-product-images-in-category-page/